# adapt scrolling/swiping to e-ink screens

Tags: android

Scrolling screens and animations are bad things on e-ink screens. Their fast screen refreshes make the screen wildly flicker (first going negative, then black, then new content, repeat many times for scrolling).

One simple way to tame an e-ink screen is to change scrolling to paging. Another method would be to still do scrolling - but without showing intermediate screen updates:
Screen before scroll -> lifting the finger: update to screen after scroll
Screen before scroll -> leaving the finger + timeout: update to actual screen

- Any ideas how to implement this?
- Is there a way to teach/overwrite existing scroll code?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   switch(event.getAction())
   {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         hit_scrollx = view.getScrollX();
         hit_scrolly = view.getScrollY();
         hit_touchx = (int) event.getX();
         hit_touchy = (int) event.getY();
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         int x = (int) event.getX();
         int y = (int) event.getY();
         if (x<hit_touchx-5 || x>hit_touchx+5 || y<hit_touchy-5 || y>hit_touchy+5)
            scrollAbsolute(hit_scrollx+hit_touchx-x, hit_scrolly+hit_touchy-y);
         break;
   }
   return(true);
}
```

This presumes that you have your own scrollAbsolute which does clipping for your application and uses View.scrollTo. This is designed for an activity with a main scrolling view. It captures all touch events. The "5" is to prevent unnecessary refresh on insignificant touches.